# Speeding up PSQL query for Python script

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am currently using Psycopg2 to run 4 separate SQL queries from 4 different tables.  The data itself needs to be separated for what I intend to use it for, which is why I am doing it this way.  Of the 4 SQL tables that I am pulling from, 3 are under 2mil rows, while the 4th is significantly larger at nearly 24mil rows.  It is a very simple statement, basically:

```sql
SELECT row1, row2, row3, row4 FROM largetable WHERE row1 = {value};
```

Which returns usually 10-20 matching rows.

I am designing an app for my coworkers to look up this data and display it via a Tkinter window (which I will leave out of the MCVE).  Given what they need to do with it, I need it to populate as fast as possible.  The entire load up and populate runs about 10 seconds, with about 5-6 seconds being spent solely on this one SQL.  The script grants read-only access to the database, so manipulation of the table is not possible.

Here is an MCVE of the part I need to speed up in my py script.  The SQL files all follow the simple outline above but pull from different tables.  We can say query_d is the largest.

```py
import psycopg2
from config import config
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter.messagebox

def get_val():
    class GetValue(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.label = tk.Label(text="Input Control")
            self.label.config(font=("Ariel", 24))
            self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
            self.entry.config(font=("Ariel",18),justify='center')
            self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Populate", 
            command=self.on_button)
            self.label.pack()
            self.entry.pack()
            self.button.pack(pady=5)
            self.bind("<Return>",self.on_button)
            self.bind("<KP_Enter>",self.on_button)
            self.entry.focus_force()

        def on_button(self, event=None):
            global val
            try:
                val = int(self.entry.get())
            except:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Invalid Entry", "Entry must be a 
                number.")
            else:
                if control:
                    conn = None
                    try:
                        params = config()
                        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
                        cur = conn.cursor()
                        global value
                        value = {'value':value}

                        query_a = open("query_a.sql", "r")  
                        a = query_a.read()
                        a = a.format(**value)
                        cur.execute(a)
                        global response_a
                        response_a = cur.fetchall()
                        query_a.close()

                        query_b = open("query_b.sql", "r")  
                        b = query_b.read()
                        b = b.format(**value)
                        cur.execute(b)
                        global response_b
                        response_b = cur.fetchall()
                        query_b.close()

                        query_c = open("query_c.sql", "r")  
                        c = query_c.read()
                        c = c.format(**value)
                        cur.execute(c)
                        global response_c
                        response_c = cur.fetchall()
                        query_c.close()
                        
                        query_d = open("query_d.sql", "r")  
                        d = query_d.read()
                        d = d.format(**value)
                        cur.execute(d)
                        global response_d
                        response_d = cur.fetchall()
                        query_d.close()

                    finally:
                        if conn is not None:
                        conn.close()
    app = GetValue()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_control()
```

With these factors in mind, is it possible to speed up this query?

Comment: 5 seconds is a long time for that kind of query. Are you missing an index on `row1`?

Comment: I am relatively new to SQL and I didn't set up this database.  I'm not familiar with index, but what I just read about it, it sounds promising, however, the key value to search for changes on each search, which I didn't mention in the op and will correct.  I think because of this, I couldn't use index in that manner.  Please let me know if I'm wrong.  Updating OP now.

Comment: You say value changes for each search. This does not preclude using an index, it is the purpose of the index; access based on value. If you actually mean the column name(s) change then you will need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Really?  It may be that I just don't understand how to use index.  I will research further.  The column name definitely does not change.  I have updated the op with the tkinter get value box.

Comment: Consider using using [**parameters**](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html) which `psycopg2` absolutely supports and recommends. While here you check for integers in user input, later on you may accept string input and a clever, malicious user can [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) your database! Also, use context manager, `with`, to read the .sql files and DRY-er (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself) code for query calls with a defined method or loop.

Comment: Hah, I do love that one.  I get the .sql files, format them with the user input which only takes numbers, and then run the query.  I think that prevents me from running into the Bobby Tables scenario.  Thank you for the suggestions, they are very helpful.  I'm looking into psycopg2 parameters now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @jordanm and @Belayer I have added an index to each table and increased the speed from about 7-8 seconds to about 0.12 seconds.